# Open a form on click a button and dissable the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I know it's a silly question but i don't know where to start to develop this. 
I have a form which is get details from user . I want when i click on a button a div appear on center and background disable and blur using jquery, javascript, hover

Comment: This is easy program-able with following keywords: 'javascript blur', 'display:none', 'set css with javascript'

Comment: Would you want something pretty similar to this: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal ?

Comment: Yeh i want like this bt in jquery not ui

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishsrivastava22/jdKPj/ Form

Comment: I think you are talking about a pop-up ...

Comment: Yeh like popup .. and blur the background also 
i am tired doing google bt i don't get it

Comment: can you please show a demo link ?

Comment: Yeh http://jsfiddle.net/ashishsrivastava22/jdKPj/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for modal(Popover).

Here is [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/7zHBG/) of it. Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/mmfansler/aQ3Ge/show/">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use <strike>Bootstrap</strike> Here is [Another Example](http://codepen.io/maba/pen/nbzBC)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Design two divs..

**Markup:**

```
<div class="DivPopup"> 
    //Add controls as you wish
 </div>
<div class="DivCover" ></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.DivAlert
{
    z-index:22;
    //You can add css styles as you wish
}
.DivCover
{
    opacity:0.4;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:21;
    background-color:White;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(".DivCover").show();
 $(".DivAlert").show();
```

Don't take this as the final answer to your question.Just a guidance.